# Integrate FxCop in VS 2010 modifying csproj file using Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-automation, add-in, projects-and-solutions, fxcop

I have many projects in TFS, using VS2010. I have a Addin VS2010 that add some new business features for my company.

Now, it is required integrate FxCop and Visual Studio 2010 for older and new projects.

I(we) don't want to add FxCopCmd.exe to my Post-build events  to run FxCop with every compilation.

I(we) don't want to modify Microsoft.CSharp.targets or Microsoft.Common.targets.

I want the programmer don't do anything, not modify properties project, not modify xml csproj file.

I want to be able to run FxCop when the programmer do Build on the project in Solution Explorer, and too when do Build programatically in Addin:

```
solution.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution", "");
project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSelection", "");
```

I think the better option is using Solution Events in Addin VS2010 for modify csproj file

```
solutionEvents.ProjectAdded
solutionEvents.Opened
```

Any suggestions about all this ? any sample source code ?

Comment: Thanks for the blog comment. Unfortunately I don't use FxCop anymore and I'm not sure how best to achieve your result.